# Sane number of BackgroundWorker thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I am writing an 'Admin Console' that accesses [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) via its provided COM interface. I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. In one procedure, it scans for the whole accounts. Because it's a lengthy procedure, I shove it into a set of BackgroundWorker threads.

First result: A maximum of 19 simultaneous threads, with 36 seconds total time.

Then I rewrote a time consuming thread initialization code segment, and managed to reduce the time required to approximately 14 seconds... but the thread count now hit 330 threads!

Will that *huge* amount of threads be detrimental? E.g., causing out-of-memory exceptions &c. ?

Comment: The server administrator will eventually find you and hurt you.

Comment: @Hans since it happens that I *am* the server's administrator, I don't think I need to be scared of that, heh :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a vb expert by any means, but why not limit the number of these background threads to be some multiple of the number of cores available on your machine?  A huge amount of threads most likely will cause out of memory issues, or thread starvation.

Comment: Because the threads are mostly blocked on the server side. Limiting the number of threads to the number of cores means the threads will spend most of their time being idle.

Comment: I said a multiple of the # of cores, not the exact number of cores.  Also, I don't know how creating more threads alleviates your blockage

Comment: @Amir ah, I misunderstood. The point was when a thread was blocked by the server, the other thread(s) can continue processing the information already retrieved from the server. Anyways, I'm experimenting with limiting the number of threads now.

Comment: @Amir okay, I've found diminishing returns above 12 simultaneous threads. So I'm going to hard-limit the BackgroundWorker threads to 12. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Anytime.  I recommended a number that scales to cores so your program isn't tuned for one machine only.

Comment: @Amir good idea. Since my dev machine has 2 cores, I guess I'll just do 6 * (number of cores). Thanks again!